# Make view controller change wait for end of custom animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to perform a custom animation inside my `UIViewController` when it appears and disappears. On the disappearing part, I was wondering if I could make it delay for a length of time that would allow me to perform the transition before it disappears? So the `UINavigationController` runs `popViewController` and then allows the `UIViewController` some time to do a custom animation before it happens.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this solution when you press the back button.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            // your custom animation
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.navigationController popViewController];
        }];
```